# Does matching in ocaml call the constructor?

Tags: ocaml

Let's say I define a type in OCaml this way:

```
type 'a foo = My_none | Bar of 'a;;
```

When making

```
let a = Bar 4;;
```

The `Bar` constructor is "called".

In the following function, does the matching call the constructor, or simply "recognize" the pattern without calling the constructor?

```
let get_bar x = match x with
     | My_none -> failwith "None"
     | Bar z -> z;;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> does the matching call the constructor, or simply "recognize" the pattern without calling the constructor?

The latter. Matching against `Bar z` does not create a new `Bar` value. It simply checks whether `x` is a `Bar` value.

Comment: This is the right way to think about pattern matching, but as far as I know there's no actual guarantee that matching will be implemented this way. The compiler and runtime can do things however they like as long as the observable results are the same. The construction  of a new value doesn't have observable side-efects, so it could in theory be happening. (But it isn't.)

Comment: You can also think of your datatype definition as creating both a *value constructor* and a *pattern constructor* with identical names, where the latter is actually a *value destructor* in the sense that it destructures parts of the value (in order to access its properties).